# Gitlab-CI run Stage conditionally

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**As you see below I have two stages.**

1- Build

2- Deploy

**And I have 3 kind of branches**

1- master

2- test

3- Other branches which created by developers. (Development)

I want to run build for all branches but I have a condition for deploy

1- If branch is test run deploy.

2- If branch is other branches don't run deploy.

3- if branch is master run deploy only manual.

But this three condition doesn't works properly with my gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
default:
  image: node:latest

  before_script:
    - |
      if [ "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" == "master" ]; then
          ENV="prod"
      elif [ "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" == "test" ]; then
          ENV="test"
      else
          ENV="dev"
      fi
    - npm install

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cp ./src/env-${ENV}.js ./src/env.js
    - npm run build-compressed

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules: //this section doesn't work properly
    - if: '$ENV == "test"'
      when: always
    - if: '$ENV == "prod"'
      when: manual
    - when: never
  script:
    - cp ./src/env-${ENV}.js ./src/env.js
    - npm run build-compressed
    - npm run publish:${ENV}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing such a differentiation via Rules. As you can easily override variables with rules, see [GitLab CI Doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesvariables).

Below you can find a short example

```
rules
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /test/
  variables:                              # Override ENV defined
    ENV: "test"  # at the job level.
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /master/
  variables:                              # Override ENV defined
    ENV: "prod"  # at the job level.
- variables: # not 100% sure about this one, as when can stand without a if clause, i assume variables can too :D
    ENV: "dev"
```

Furthermore i would also do the rule check based on the branch within the deploy stage. - as it is easier to verify the branch, than to ensure at a later stage, that the Env variable is still set properly.

Also important to notice is the order of evaluation. Just because there is a `before_script` in the default section, does not mean it is evaluated just once for the whole. The `before_script` is evaluated once per Job.

Additionally the rules are evaluated, before the JOB runs, as it needs to determine if the job should be executed or not. This means you are not able to reference the variable from the `before_script`.

If you want to pass on the variable from the first job to the second job, you need to persist it in a [dotenv-artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#inherit-cicd-variables) - this way, the variables are available before the second stage start. (I am still not sure if you can use them for evaluation in rules, that is something you need to check)

I hope my additional clarifications, based on your comments, help you to find the best way.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there is no error about variables. The condition not working for me which is starting deploy: -> stage: deploy -> rules:

Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: i am not 100% sure they will be carried on to the next stage successfully. hence that i recommend to use the rules, than the before script. If you want to pass on a env variable, you need to have a dotenv artifact (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) - and they will be automatically used. I assume, that the env variable in the before script is evaluated too late. After the rules are checked, and it is not carried over to the next stage automatically

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#inherit-cicd-variables

Comment: I'm sure that ENV variable carried in to Deploy section because when I use echo it, I can see the ENV as test.

Comment: the before script runs before each job - not before the whole pipeline, thats why the env variable is there in your job

Comment: Ok, I have understood what you mean at the end. I will fix it. Thanks.